# What was the full text of Brazil's resolution that the US vetoed regarding Israel?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, reference-request, unsc, 2023-israel-hamas-war

[US veto at UN to shield Israel could weaken its Ukraine rallying cry | Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/us-veto-un-shield-israel-could-weaken-its-ukraine-rallying-cry-2023-10-20/)

> The U.S. veto in the U.N. Security Council bolstered long-held criticisms of the West by Russia, China and some developing countries and could once again hinder Washington's immediate ability to win backing for issues tied to human rights and humanitarian law
>
> "The wider world will see an equivalence between this veto by the U.S. and Russia's behavior over Ukraine. Moscow and Beijing will emphasize this point whenever they can," said Richard Gowan, U.N. director at the International Crisis Group.
>
> "Everyone knows Israel is a special case for the U.S., but **the Americans ultimately slapped down a text that was very mild and humanitarian in focus,"** he said. The vetoed text included calls for pauses in the conflict to allow aid access to Gaza and for all parties to comply with international law.
>
> Thomas-Greenfield said the **U.S. was disappointed the draft resolution made no mention of Israel's rights of self-defense.** She left the door open to future U.N. action, but said the council "needs to get this right."

I have seen a number of articles about this resolution but could not find the actual full text, which is likely to be short.  I would also be curious to know which parts, if any, were introduced by Russian amendments.

Comment: The Russian amendments were rejected separately, IIRC.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  Making it all the more interesting to see what was in it, as Russia was asking for a ceasefire which would suit Hamas just fine, but wouldn't have been in it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's S/2023/773 that [was](https://research.un.org/en/docs/sc/quick/meetings/2023) vetoed by the US (votes: 12-1-2).

> Brazil: draft resolution
>
> The Security Council,
> Guided by the purposes and principles of the Charter of the United Nations,
>
> Recalling resolutions 242 (1967), 338 (1973), 446 (1979), 452 (1979), 465
> (1980), 476 (1980), 478 (1980), 1397 (2002), 1515 (2003), and 1850 (2008) and 2334 (2016),
>
> Reaffirming that any acts of terrorism are criminal and unjustifiable regardless of their motivations, whenever and by whomsoever committed,
>
> Expressing grave concern at the escalation of violence and the deterioration of the situation in the region, in particular the resulting heavy civilian casualties, an demphasizing that civilians in Israel and in the occupied Palestinian territory, including East Jerusalem, must be protected, in accordance with international humanitarian law,
>
> Expressing deep concern for the humanitarian situation in Gaza and for its grave effect for the civilian population, largely comprised of children, and underlining the need for full, rapid, safe and unhindered humanitarian access,
>
> Encouraging efforts aiming at a cessation of hostilities that would help to ensure the protection of civilians both in Israel and in the occupied Palestinian territory, including East Jerusalem,
>
> Reiterating its vision of a region where two democratic States, Israel and
> Palestine, live side by side in peace within secure and recognized borders,
> Recalling that a lasting solution to the Israeli-Palestinian conflict can only be achieved by peaceful means, based on its relevant resolutions,
>
> 1. Firmly condemns all violence and hostilities against civilians and all acts of terrorism;
> 2. Unequivocally rejects and condemns the heinous terrorist attacks by
>    Hamas that took place in Israel starting 7 October 2023 and the taking of hostages;
> 3. Calls for the immediate and unconditional release of all hostages,
>    demanding for their safety, well-being, and humane treatment in compliance with international law;
> 4. Urges all parties to fully comply with their obligations under international law, including international human rights law and international humanitarian law, including those related to the conduct of hostilities, including in relation to the protection of civilians and civilian infrastructure, as well as humanitarian workers and assets and to allow for and facilitate humanitarian access for essential supplies and services to those in need;
> 5. Strongly urges the continuous, sufficient and unhindered provision of
>    essential goods and services to civilians, including electricity, water, fuel, food, and medical supplies, stressing the imperative, under international humanitarian law, to
>    ensure civilians are not deprived of objects indispensable to their survival;
> 6. Calls for the rescission of the order for civilians and UN staff to evacuate all areas in Gaza north of the Wadi Gaza and relocate in southern Gaza;
> 7. Calls for humanitarian pauses to allow full, rapid, safe and unhindered
>    humanitarian access for United Nations humanitarian agencies and their
>    implementing partners, the International Committee of the Red Cross and other
>    impartial humanitarian organizations, and encourages the establishment of
>    humanitarian corridors and other initiatives for the delivery of humanitarian aid to civilians;
> 8. Stresses the importance of a humanitarian notification mechanism to
>    protect UN facilities and all humanitarian sites, and to ensure the movement of aid convoys;
> 9. Calls for the respect and protection, consistent with international
>    humanitarian law, of all medical personnel and humanitarian personnel exclusively
>    engaged in medical duties, their means of transport and equipment, as well as
>    hospitals and other medical facilities;
> 10. Emphasizes the importance of preventing spillover in the region and, in
>     this regard, calls on all parties to exercise maximum restraint and on all those with
>     influence on them to work toward this objective;
> 11. Decides to remain seized of the matter.

The Russian amendments "not adopted" were S/2023/775 (votes: 6-1-8) and  S/2023/776 (votes: 7-1-7)

The first of these ammendments was:

> Russian Federation: amendment to the draft resolution contained
> in document S/2023/773
>
> After operative paragraph 2, insert a new paragraph:
>
> 3. Also unequivocally condemns indiscriminate attacks against civilians as
>    well as against civilian objects in the Gaza Strip resulting in civilian casualties, in
>    particular the heinous strike against Al Ahli hospital, and condemns and rejects the
>    actions to impose the blockade of the Gaza Strip depriving civilian population of
>    means indispensable for their survival, in violation of international humanitarian
>    law;

The 2nd:

> Russian Federation: amendment to the draft resolution contained
> in document S/2023/773
>
> Before operative paragraph 1, insert a new paragraph:
>
> 1. Calls for an immediate, durable and fully respected humanitarian ceasefire;